# Calculating $\int_C v\cdot t ds$ when $C$ is $y=\sin x$ and $v(x,y) = (y+e^x, 1)$

Tags: proof-verification, vector-analysis

> Find $\int_C v\cdot t ds$ when $C$ is $y=\sin x, 0\leq x \leq \pi $ and $v(x,y) = (y+e^x, 1)$, and $t$ is the unit tangent to $C$.

This is the first question of a vector analysis exam I am doing and I keep getting something not very nice, and I am not sure if the lecturer has made a mistake or if I am wrong.

So I parameterise $C$ by $r(t) = (t, \sin t), 0 \leq t \leq \pi$.

The unit tangent to $C$ is then $\frac{r'(t)}{||r'(t)||} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}} (1, \cos t)$

So then $$\int_C v\cdot t ds = \int_0^{\pi} (\sin t + e^t, 1) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}} (1, \cos t)\right)dt$$ $$ = \int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}} (\sin t + e^t + \cos t)dt$$

which I see no easy way of integrating.

I presume I am wrong somewhere, but I don't know where. A picture of the actual question is attached if my recreation isn't clear enough. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot your $ds$ in $$ \int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}} (\sin t + e^t + \cos t)dt$$

When you include your ds, the integral simplifies and you can evaluate it easily.

Comment: What is the $ds$?

Comment: $ds = \|\frac {dr}{dt}\| dt.$  The "unit tangent" ultimately is a canard.

Comment: I'm sorry, so I am meant to work out the dot product and then times it by $||\frac{dr}{dt} || dt$? Could you perhaps write an answer that explains what exactly the definition is for that integral? I understand how to find a line integral $\int_C v\cdot ds$, not too sure with the $t$ there...

Comment: replace  your dt with  ds=\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t} and cancel the radicals.

Comment: Then what do I integrate with respect to?

Comment: I meant  $ds=\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}dt$ your integration is with respect to  $t$.

Comment: Then I get $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1+ \cos^2 t} (\sin t + e^t + \cos t) dt$ which isn't easy either...

Comment: You have not canceled the square roots. You multiplied them and got a  fraction which should not be there at all.